# Possible mistaken empty statement

Tags: c#

Buenas no soy muy freceunte en preguntar por aca pero si uso mucho la pag para resolveerme problemas que me surgen, asi que hiper agradecido con toda la comunidad.

Ahora no pude encontrar el error en mi codigo, alguien me podria aydar. en con C#

```
using (System.Linq);

string sellers = {!client.CL.sellers}

string[] splitSellers = sellers.Split(new string[] { "--" }, StringSplitOptions.None)

splitSellers = splitSellers.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray()
splitSellers = splitSellers.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray()

Array.Resize(ref splitSellers, splitSellers.Length + 1)

splitSellers[splitSellers.Length - 1] = {!seller.SE.sellerId}

return  ("--" + String.Join("--", splitSellers) + "--")
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Intenta [edit] tu pregunta para dar algo mas de información. Que hace el codigo? Que error te da? En que línea? Ayudanos a ayudarte :)

Comment: En tu caso, si es lo que comentas en el titulo, no es un error, sino una advertencia, y parece estar provocada por la primera fila de tu código.  Si lo que quieres añadir es un `using` para hacer uso de Linq, este debe ir en las primeras lineas de tu código, y no entre parentesis. Por otro lado, el codigo que pones es un poco raro...no estas usando `;` para finalizar cada una de las sentencias...